# Trying to calulate irr using sql stored procedure, help needed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, irr

```
CREATE procedure testXIRR
(
@AmountEstimate as float = 0,
@AmountGoal as float = 0,
@AmountPrecision as float = 1e-7 ,
@AmountPrevious as float = 0,
@EndDate as date = null,
@FlagError as bit = 0,
@FlagLoop as bit = 1,
@Rate as float = 0.1,
@RateDelta as float = 1e-2,
@RateInitial as float = 0,
@RateUpDown as smallint = 0,
@TableName as varchar(20) = NULL,
@query as varchar(20) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN 
Declare @powerVariable as float

Declare @MyTable Table(
PDate date,
PAmount float
)
insert into @MyTable values('01-Jan-13',-500),('01-Feb-13',20),('01-Mar-13',50),('01-Apr-13',80),('01-May-13',110),('01-Jun-13',140),('01-Jul-13',170)
set @Rate = @RateInitial
select @AmountGoal = -PAmount, @EndDate = PDate from @MyTable where PAmount < 0 

while @FlagLoop = 1 
    begin
        if abs(@AmountEstimate - @AmountGoal) < @AmountPrecision or ABS(@Rate) > 1
            set @FlagLoop = 0
        else
            begin
                if (@AmountPrevious is not null) 
                    begin   
                        if @AmountPrevious < @AmountGoal and @AmountEstimate < @AmountGoal
                            set @RateUpDown = 1
                        if @AmountPrevious > @AmountGoal and @AmountEstimate > @AmountGoal 
                            set @RateUpdown = -1 
                        if (@AmountPrevious < @AmountGoal and @AmountEstimate > @AmountGoal) or (@AmountPrevious > @AmountGoal and @AmountEstimate < @AmountGoal) 
                            set @RateDelta = @RateDelta / 2e0
                    end
                set @AmountPrevious = @AmountEstimate 
                set @Rate = (@Rate + (@RateDelta * @RateUpDown))
                select @AmountEstimate = SUM(power(1e0 + @Rate, DATEDIFF(m,@EndDate , PDate)) * PAmount)  from @MyTable where PAmount >= 0

            end
        end
  print @Rate  
if Abs(@Rate) > 1 
    begin
        set @FlagError = 1
        print   -100000000
    end
else
    begin
        print   @Rate
        end
END
GO
```

For the above values excel gives irr = 43.5976392, but this sp gives -2.9%.

At first it was giving an error:

> invalid float operation

To fix that I have changed the formula from
`SUM(power(1e0 + @Rate, DATEDIFF(d, PDate, @EndDate) / 365e0) * PAmount)` 
to 
`SUM(power(1e0 + @Rate, DATEDIFF(m,@EndDate , PDate)) * PAmount)`.

This resolved the issure which i think was square root of negative but still values are wrong.

Comment: Could you explain what the goal of the above SQL is? you say you you did this in Excel as well, what was the formula you used in Excel?

Comment: the line of code before the fix implies a daily interest calculation, and the second line is a monthly interest calculation

Comment: @Larnu in excel i have calculated it like xirr(values,date_range)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XIRR Calc in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20972209/xirr-calc-in-sql)

Comment: NB - the questioner has said he is fully satisfied by the existing answer (see comment below my answer)